# Why does adding Bootstrap stop my Flask application from working?

Tags: python, flask, bootstrap-4

I am learning Flask for the first time so I created a basic application of adding names into an unordered list. The names which is inserted are taken input in a input field. Basically when I didn't add Bootstrap it was working fine but when I added Bootstrap it is doing nothing when I click the button.

Code when no Bootstrap

```
<form action="{{ url_for('index') }}" method="POST">

        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" style="border-radius: 20px;">

            <button>Click Me!</button>



</form>

    <ul>
        {% for item in task  %}
        <li> {{ item }} </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Code when Bootstrap added :

```
<form action="{{ url_for('index') }}" method="POST">
    <div class="input-group col-lg-10 col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name" 
style="border-radius: 20px;">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Click Me!</button>
        </span>
    </div>

</form>

    <ul>
        {% for item in task  %}
        <li> {{ item }} </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

This is my application.py :

```
from flask import Flask


from flask import render_template,request


app = Flask(__name__)

task=[]

@app.route("/",methods=["GET","POST"])

def index():

    if request.method=="POST":

        name = request.form.get("name")

        task.append(name)

    return render_template("index.html",task=task)
```

Comment: Do you get a JavaScript error in your browser console when you click the button?

Comment: are you sure it should be `type="button"` ? Maybe `type="submit"` ? It can change behavior even without `Bootstrap`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem probably is not `Bootstrap` but `type="button"`.

If you use `type="button"` in `<button>` even without `Bootstrap` then you have the same problem.

You have to remove it or use `type="submit"`.

In `<button>` you can use only

- `type="submit"` to send form to server
- `type="reset"` to clear form (without sending to server)
- `type="button"` to create clickable button but it doesn't send to server and you can assign JavaScript code which run some function after clicking.

---

**BTW:** I'm not sure but maybe `Bootstrap` has some JavaScript file which you has to link in HTML to change button behavior when you use `type="button"`.

---

Minimal working example

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template_string, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET","POST"])
def index():
    if request.method=="POST":
        name = request.form.get("name")
        print(name)
    return render_template_string("""<form action="{{ url_for('index') }}" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
<br>
<button>Button without Type</button>
<br>
<button type="submit">Button type="Submit"</button>
<button type="reset">Button type="Reset"</button>
<button type="button">Button type="Button"</button>
<button type="button" onclick="alert('Clicked')">Button type="Button" with JavaScript</button>
<br>
<input type="submit" value='Input type="Submit"'/>
<input type="reset" value='Input type="Reset"'/>
<input type="button" value='Input type="Button"'/>
<input type="button" onclick="alert('Clicked')" value='Input type="Button" with JavaScript"'/>
</form>""")

app.run()
```

---

Doc: [< button >](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp), [< input >](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Change `<button>` to `<input type=“submit” value=“Click Me! />`. You can add whatever bootstrap classes you want to style this submit input like a button.